DHT11 Sensor - reading either all zeros or all -999 (depending on library)
So I've been trying to get a small project set up for the upcoming eclipse, just to read changes in the humidity and temp during the eclipse.
I have two DHT11 sensors, I'm only using one.
I have downloaded this library (it's at the bottom), and this is the code I'm using.
#include <dht.h>
#define pin 13
dht DHT;
void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(2500);
  Serial.print("DHT11 Sensor: April 8 Solar eclipse data\n\n");
  delay(1500);
}

void loop() {
  DHT.read11(pin);
    Serial.print(" ");
    Serial.print(DHT.humidity);
    Serial.print(" ");
    Serial.print(DHT.temperature);
    Serial.print(",\n");
    delay(2500);
    

}

The goal here is to have csv's that I can copy/paste into a .csv and import to matlab to do what I need on there.
I keep getting the title and "0.00 0.00," for the two data sets.
With other libraries and borrowed code sometimes I get -999 for the datasets.
My set up

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
My schematic isn't super accurate, the sensor's on the breadboard. LMK your thoughts.

@StarCat just delete the comment then

I attempted the resistor, I put one end in the power row between the 5V into the breadboard and the power pin for the sensor, and the other end into a slot between the data wire out to the Mega, and the pin for the sensor.
Still zeros.

Try a pin other than 13.  There is additional circuitry around pin 13 for the built in LED.

Can be a bad sensor or bad cable too.

You can cross-check your sensor with this tutorial. https://www.theengineeringprojects.com/2017/08/dht11-arduino-interfacing.html If your sensor does not work after following this, maybe you have to replace your sensor.

If you are using a standalone DHT11 sensor (Without breakout board) you will need a 1KΩ pullup-resistor between 5v and Data.
The DHT's data pin is an open collector, meaning it can only pull a wire to ground to transmit data. If that wire wasn't pulled up to begin with, it won't have anything to pull down.
If your DHT11 is on a breakout board with the 1KΩ resistor already in place, I would suspect a bad sensor...

I have used DHT11's successfully in at least two different projects. Take a look at https://www.fpaynter.com/2021/07/temperature-display-for-3d-printer-enclosure/ and https://www.fpaynter.com/2017/01/3d-printer-filament-de-humidifier-bin/.  Both these posts have the entire code.
